# Msp430 I2C Single Byte Read Write

Tags: i2c, msp430, interrupts

I have this code I've been working on that connects an ITG-3200 gyroscope slave and MSP430G2553 master via I2C bus. It was working fine yesterday but somehow today it is not working. I tried to debug as much as I can without gyro ACK but it seems that after going into LPM TX interrupt never occur so it stuck in the LPM. Can you check out to see something I'm missing? I tried to clean up the code as much as possible and it might seem like a bit complicated code but feel free to ask about any function.

```
/* --COPYRIGHT--,
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Barışcan Kayaoğlu
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * --COPYRIGHT--*/
//******************************************************************************
//  MSP430G2xx3 I2C Demo - USCI_B0 I2C Master TX/RX single byte from ITG-3200
//  gyroscope.
//
//  Description: This demo connects a MSP430Gxx3 launchpad to ITG-3200 via
//  USCI_B0 I2C module. The launchpad act as a master and itg-300 act as a
//  slave. Master reads 6 byte consecutively and send it to the vitual COM
//  Port on Usb with USCI_A0 Uart module. DCO = 1MHz
//
//                                /|\  /|\
//                  ITG-3200      10k  10k     MSP430G2xx3
//                   slave         |    |        master
//             -----------------   |    |     -----------------
//            |              SDA|<-|----+---->|P1.7/UCB0SDA     |
//            |              CLK|<-|-.GND     |                 |
//            |              GND|<-|-'        |                 |
//            |              SCL|<-+--------->|P1.6/UCB0SCL     |
//            |              VCC|<--.         |      P1.1/UCA0TX|-------> COM Port (9600 baud)
//            |              VIO|<--'3.3V     |                 |
//            |              INT|             |                 |
//  Barışcan Kayaoğlu
//  May 2013
//  Built with CCS Version 5.3.0.00090
//******************************************************************************
#include <msp430g2553.h>

int TXByteCtr; // This counter used for counting bytes before the stop condition
char xRate_L;  // Variable to hold X_Low register value
char xRate_H;  // Variable to hold X_High register value
char yRate_L;  // Variable to hold Y_Low register value
char yRate_H;  // Variable to hold Y_High register value
char zRate_L;  // Variable to hold Z_Low register value
char zRate_H;  // Variable to hold Z_High register value
int i2c_State; // This counter held the state machine condition of I2C
int Rx = 0;    // Flag for the interrupt vector. 1 for Receive 0 for Transmit
int init = 0;  // Flag for the interrupt vector. 1 for Writing to gyro for config 0 for reading

//Gyro configuration addresses
char WHO_AM_I = 0x00;   // Gyro register where it helds the slave address 0x69 | 0x68
char SMPLRT_DIV= 0x15; // Gyro register where it helds the divider value for sample rate
char DLPF_FS = 0x16;  // Gyro register where it helds the low pass filter config

//Gyro Memory addresses;
char GYRO_XOUT_H = 0x1D;
char GYRO_XOUT_L = 0x1E;
char GYRO_YOUT_H = 0x1F;
char GYRO_YOUT_L = 0x20;
char GYRO_ZOUT_H = 0x21;
char GYRO_ZOUT_L = 0x22;
char TEMP_OUT_H = 0x1B;
char TEMP_OUT_L = 0x1C;
char itgAddress = 0x69;

//Gyro configuration constants
char DLPF_CFG_0 = 1<<0;        // 1
char DLPF_CFG_1 = 1<<1;       // 10
char DLPF_CFG_2 = 1<<2;      // 100
char DLPF_FS_SEL_0 = 1<<3;  // 1000
char DLPF_FS_SEL_1 = 1<<4; //10000

void init_I2C(void);
void Transmit(void);
void Receive(void);
void initUart(void);
void initGyro(void);

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;                    // Set DCO to 1Mhz
  DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;
  //__delay_cycles(15000);                  // Wait gyro to wake up
  P1SEL |= BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT6 + BIT7;       // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0 // Assign Uart pins to USCI_A0
  P2SEL |= BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT6 + BIT7;       // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0 // Assign Uart pins to USCI_A0
  init_I2C();
  initUart();
  initGyro();
  init = 0;                                 // Flag to reading from configuration writing

  while(1) {
      switch(i2c_State) {
          case 0: // Wait state
            __delay_cycles(8000);
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 1: // Read X_High state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 2: // Read X_Low state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 3: // Read Y_High state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 4: // Read Y_Low state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 5: // Read Z_High state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 6: // Read Z_Low state
            Rx = 0; // Receive flag = transmit
            TXByteCtr = 1; // TXByteCtr 1 for sending register address and stop
            Transmit();  // I2C start condition with Write operation

            Rx = 1; // Receive flag = receive
            Receive();  // I2C start condition with Read operation
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 7:
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x58; // X
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x3A; // :
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = xRate_H;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = xRate_L;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x09; // tab
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 8:
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x59; // Y
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x3A; // :
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = yRate_H;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = yRate_L;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x09; // tab
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            i2c_State++;
            break;
          case 9:
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x5A; // Z
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x3A; // :
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = zRate_H;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = zRate_L;
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x5C; // \
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            UCA0TXBUF = 0x6E; // n
            while (!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));                // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
            i2c_State = 0;
            break;
      } // End of state machine
  }
} // End of Main


 void readX_H() {
      if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve
          xRate_H = UCB0RXBUF;                  // Get RXBuffer value to xRate_H
      }

      else {                                     // Master Transmit
          if (TXByteCtr) {                       // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
              UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_XOUT_H;           // Load TX buffer // request from X_High register
              TXByteCtr--;                       // Decrement TX byte counter
          }
          else {                                      // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }

  void readX_L() {
      if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve
          xRate_L = UCB0RXBUF;                  // Get RXBuffer value to xRate_L
      }

      else {                                     // Master Transmit
          if (TXByteCtr) {                       // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
              UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_XOUT_L;           // Load TX buffer // request from X_Low register
              TXByteCtr--;                       // Decrement TX byte counter
          }
          else {                                      // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }

  void readY_H() {
      if(Rx == 1) {                              // Master Recieve
          yRate_H = UCB0RXBUF;                   // Get RXBuffer value to yRate_H
      }

      else {                                         // Master Transmit
          if (TXByteCtr) {                           // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
              UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_YOUT_H;               // Load TX buffer // request from Y_High register
              TXByteCtr--;                           // Decrement TX byte counter
          }
          else {                                        // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                      // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                       // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }

  void readY_L() {
      if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve
          yRate_L = UCB0RXBUF;                  // Get RXBuffer value to yRate_L
      }

      else {                                     // Master Transmit
          if (TXByteCtr) {                       // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
              UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_YOUT_L;           // Load TX buffer // request from Y_Low register
              TXByteCtr--;                       // Decrement TX byte counter
          }
          else {                                      // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }


  void readZ_H() {
      if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve
          zRate_H = UCB0RXBUF;                  // Get RXBuffer value to zRate_H
      }

      else {                                     // Master Transmit
          if (TXByteCtr) {                       // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
              UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_ZOUT_H;           // Load TX buffer // request from Z_High register
              TXByteCtr--;                       // Decrement TX byte counter
          }
          else {                                      // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }

  void readZ_L() {
      if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve
          zRate_L = UCB0RXBUF;                   // Get RXBuffer value to zRate_L
      }

      else {                                     // Master Transmit
         if (TXByteCtr)  {                       // TX byte counter = 1 : send gyro address
             UCB0TXBUF = GYRO_ZOUT_L;            // Load TX buffer // request from Z_Low register
             TXByteCtr--;                        // Decrement TX byte counter
         }
         else {                                       // Tx byte counter = 0 : register address sent
              UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
              IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX interrupt flag
          }
      }
  }

  void initGyro(void) {
    TXByteCtr = 2;  // 2 bytes will occur. First register address send, Second Data send
    init = 1;       // config flag to 1 : Sending Divider value
    Transmit();     // Start condition with Writing mode
    init = 2;       // config flag to 2 : Sending Low pass filter value
    TXByteCtr = 2;  // Restart byte counter
    Transmit();     // Start condition with Writing mode
  }

  void init_I2C(void) {
      UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
      UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master, synchronous mode
      UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;            // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
      UCB0BR0 = 10;                             // fSCL = 1Mhz/10 = ~100kHz
      UCB0BR1 = 0;
      UCB0I2CSA = itgAddress;                   // Slave Address is 069h
      UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
      IE2 |= UCB0RXIE + UCB0TXIE;               // Enable RX and TX interrupt
  }
  void initUart(void) {
      UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;                     // Use SMCLK
      UCA0BR0 = 104;                            // 1MHz 9600
      UCA0BR1 = 0;                              // 1MHz 9600
      UCA0MCTL = UCBRS0;                        // Modulation UCBRSx = 1
      UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
  }
  void Transmit(void){
      while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
      UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX with start condition
      __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
  }
  void Receive(void){
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
        UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR ;                     // Clear I2C TX flag
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                    // I2C start condition
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // Start condition sent?
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
  }

  void twosCompToDecimal() {

  }

#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR       // USCI TX interrupt vector. I2C module share RX and TX interrupts.
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)    // This will occur either when RXBuffer is full or TXBuffer is sent.
{
    if(init == 1) {                 // Gyro writing for configuration. Sending LPF register address
        if (TXByteCtr == 2) {       // byte counter = 2 : sending register address
            UCB0TXBUF = DLPF_FS;    // Low pass filter value register address to TXBuffer
            TXByteCtr--;            // Decrement TX byte counter
        }
        else if(TXByteCtr == 1) {                                       // byte counter = 1 : sending config value
              UCB0TXBUF = (DLPF_FS_SEL_0|DLPF_FS_SEL_1|DLPF_CFG_0);     // config value to TXBuffer
              TXByteCtr--;                                              // Decrement TX byte counter
        }
        else {                                      // byte counter = 0 : stop condition
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
            IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX int flag
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
    }
    else if(init == 2) {                // Gyro writing for configuration. Sending Sample Rate Divider register address
        if (TXByteCtr == 2) {           // byte counter = 1 : sending config value
            UCB0TXBUF = SMPLRT_DIV;     // Sample Rate Divider value to TXBuffer
            TXByteCtr--;                // Decrement TX byte counter
        }
        else if(TXByteCtr == 1) {           // byte counter = 1 : sending config value
            UCB0TXBUF = 9;                  // config value to TXBuffer
            TXByteCtr--;                    // Decrement TX byte counter
        }
        else {                                      // byte counter = 0 : stop condition
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
            IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX int flag
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
    }
    else {  // Gyro Reading operation.
      switch(i2c_State) {
          case 1: // Read X High
              readX_H();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
          case 2: // Read X Low
            readX_L();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
          case 3: // Read Y High
            readY_H();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
          case 4: // Read Y Low
            readY_L();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
         case 5: // Read Z High
            readZ_H();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
         case 6: // Read Z Low
            readZ_L();
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
              break;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: How about comparing the differences of the last known working program and this one?

Comment: Well that is the real issue here. There is no differences between two of them. The only difference was to move the code from my notebook to my desktop. After failing i opened up my notebook again and uploaded my code to the launchpad but the result was oddly same.

Comment: Did you remove the p1.6 led jumper?

Comment: Yes i removed the P1.6 led jumper. This was working two days ago with the same circuit except there was 2 oscilloscope on both SDA and SCL. But the circuit is working with another library.

Comment: I am new to MSP430, but i do see that P1SEL is followed by P2SEL not by P1SEL2. This may have nothing to do with this issue, but i just wanted to point and may be ask you why:)

Comment: I am currently bringing up an Adafruit I2C LED matrix on MSP430 and discovered that I was getting the device stuck in a nonresponsive state, and even cycling power to the LaunchPad didn't help because as soon as it got power it would run the last code in flash and put the peripheral back into a nonresponsive state... So I powered it through a transistor, which I toggle in my setup code with a GPIO to make sure the device is reset. Made things reliable, maybe not your problem but there are many people struggling with MSP430 I2C. Perhaps frozen peripherals is a common, unrealized problem.

Comment: Sorry that i dis not inform earlier. I solved my problem months ago but sometimes it might lock down in a busy state and its not stable, that might help thanks.